# Build for iOS release - images got lost

Tags: ios, react-native

I use the following command to build main.jsbundle

> react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js'
>   --bundle-output='./ios/billhunters/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'

It looks like assets are included in the bundle

[image]

But when I run the app on a device in the release mode, images are not there.

I add image element in my JSX the way official docs recommend:

```
<Image source={require('./assets/img/logo.png')} />
```

Has anyone encountered such issue? When the app is run in debug mode, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the article you can find below:
https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/first-time-deploying-with-react-native-f524eb3e705d

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `--assets-dest='./ios'` to `--assets-dest='./ios/billhunters'`.